# makeCards with random.h and card.h in C++

Tags: c++, random, codeblocks, playing-cards

I need to make random card deck but I'm noob, so I need some help.
And there are some orders.

1. it says I need to make enumeration type **`Rank`** and **`Suit`**
2. no-arg constructor that sets the values of the instance variables to `TWO` and
   `CLUB`S (actually I don't understand what this mean.)
3. constructor **`Card (Rank rank, Suit suit)`** that creates a `Card` object
   from the rank and suit values
4. Two accessor methods, **`Rank getRank()`** and **`Suit getSuit()`**, that allow the
   client to get the rank and suit of a Card value.
5. A function **`string toString()`** that returns a string identifying the card.

So I made some code, but still confused what I miss, and what I need.
code below:

```
// File: makeCards.cpp
// Creates some cards and displays them.

#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include "card.h"
#include "random.h"

using namespace std;

// Constants
const int NUM_CARDS = 10;

int main() {

card deck[NUM_CARDS];
Random randomizer;

for (int i = 0; i < NUM_CARDS; i++) {
  deck[i] = card((Rank) (randomizer.randomInteger(TWO, ACE)),
                     (Suit) (randomizer.randomInteger(CLUBS, HEARTS)));
}

for (int i = 0; i < NUM_CARDS; i++) {
  cout << setw(3) << deck[i].toString();
}
cout << endl << endl;

return 0;
}
```

This is main cpp which is already created.

And this is my `card.h`:

```
#ifndef CARD_H
#define CARD_H
#include <string>
using namespace std;


    enum Rank {TWO, THREE, FOUR, FIVE, SIX, SEVEN,
            EIGHT, NINE, TEN, JACK, QUEEN, KING, ACE};
    enum Suit {CLUBS, DIAMONDS,HEARTS, SPADES};

class card
{
    public:

        card();

        card(Rank rank, Suit suit);

        Rank getRank();

        Suit getSuit();

        string toString();

    private:


};

#endif // CARD_H
```

my `card.cpp`:

```
#include "card.h"

card::card()
{
    card();
}


card::card(Rank rank, Suit suit)
{
    string rank;
    string suit;
}

Rank getRank()
{
    return rank;
}

Suit getSuit()
{
    return suit;
} 

string toString()
{
    switch(rank)
    {
        case 1:
            cout<<2;
            break;
        case 2:
            cout<<3;
            break;
        default:
            cout<<"default";
    }
}
```

It's really long, but I have no idea what I need inside of

`card::card(Rank rank, Suit suit)`

and

there is an error

> `error: 'rank' was not declared in this scope`

in `card.cpp` in `toString()`, someone said using `switch` is better, so I tried but if you have better idea, let me know.

Comment: consider shuffling with http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle

Answer (score 2):

```
Rank getRank()
{
    return rank;
}
```

should be

```
Rank card::getRank()
{
    return rank;
}
```

same for the other class methods from card.cpp. They are method of the class trying to access class members.

And of course you need

```
Rank rank;
Suit suit;
```

in your class declaration.

Your constructor should be something like:

```
card::card(Rank prank, Suit psuit) : rank(prank), suit(psuit)
{
}
```

ie, you use an initialization list to initialize your member variables.

From your code:

> ```
> string rank;
> string suit;
> ```

declares two strings, but nothing else ...